# Putting a cursor in front of each highlighted word Vim Mode Plus

Tags: vim, atom-editor

How do I put a cursor in front of each highlighted word?  For instance, I want to add a prefix to some words, but when I do the `g o c i e`, it also deletes the word, which I don't want.  Is there a way to just put the cursor there without having to use `c`?

Comment: If the highlighted word is a result of a search pattern type `<esc>` to go to normal mode, then `n` to go to the next highlighted word and finally `i` to insert text in front of the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After mark occurrence by `g o`, then you can

- Select range by `cmd-a` or `g g v G` etc.
- type `I` to start insertion at start of each occurrence.
- type `A` to start insertion at end of each occurrence.

Plus if you enabled configuration from setting-view of vim-mode-plus.
You can do same thing by

- `g o I i e`(or `g o I cmd-a`), `cmd-a` in macOS is shorthand of `i e`.
- `g o A i e`(or `g o A cmd-a`)

[image]